# NSURL Path format error

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, nsurl

I have a `NSURL` path like:

`/home?mobile%3Dfalse`

But this is not recognized and returns an exception.

Any suggestions on how I can use this path correctly.

I mean i used it like

```
tempURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithScheme:@"myapp" host:@"www.abc.com" path:@"/home?mobile%3Dfalse"];
```

However the path component returns an exception saying it is not absolute.

Comment: What do you mean you have a path? How are you trying to use it?

Comment: I mean i used it like 
tempURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithScheme:@"myapp" host:@"www.abc.com" path:@"/home?mobile%3Dfalse"];

However the path component returns an exception saying it is not absolute.

Answer (score 0):

"/home?mobile%3Dfalse" is not a valid path for a [RFC1808](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1808.txt) URL. The path cannot contain a "?" character. In other words: You cannot provide the query string concatenated to the path.

You want something like:

```
[NSURL URLwithString:@"myapp://www.abc.com/home?mobile%3Dfalse"]
```

On Mac OX 10.8 the code you provided works. It only throws the exception when leaving out the leading "/".